# Sharing constants between background and popup script in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, constants

I have some constants in my extension that need to be accessed by both the popup script and the background script. Right now I'm duplicating these declarations in both.

I know I can pass messages between the scripts, but that would obviously be nonsensical - this is purely static information, and I merely want to avoid potential errors from having two sources of truth.

Is there any way to make static declarations in a place that all different parts of a Chrome extension have read access to? Or is there a different way this should be handled?

Comment: If they are _constant_ why can't you move the definitions into a script and import/include the latter from wherever you need to access these?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using manifest V3 you can use **chrome.storage.session** to save and retrieve those values.
If you're using manifest V2, you can get those values from the popup script via **chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()**

Comment: I honestly don't understand what the thread reported by the moderator has in relation to the @Krateng question and therefore I don't understand why this thread was closed.